# What does it mean for an expression to contain "at most one side effect, as its outermost operation"?

Tags: java, jls

In [Java Language Spex 15.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

> Code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side
>   effect, as its outermost operation

What does it mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that each expression should do one task at a time.

Consider the following two declarations:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
```

Now the task is to add these two `int`s and increment `b` by 1. There are two way to do it.

```
int c = a + b++;
```

and

```
int c = a + b;
b++;
```

JLS prefers and recommends the latter one.

Answer (score 5):

What this means is that:

```
int x = someFunction(a, b);
```

is clearer when `someFunction(a, b)` doesn't have any side-effect i.e. *it doesn't change anything*. Rather the only change in the above is the assignment to `x`.

Another example would be use of prefix/postfix incrementers.

```
int x = a + b;
```

is clearer than

```
int x = (a++) + (++b);
```

since only `x` is assigned to. In the second example `a` and `b` are changed in the same statement.

By limiting the side effects, you can more easily reason about the functioning of the code, and/or re-order statement invocations, including parallelising them e.g. in the below, if the methods don't have side-effects, then you can invoke the methods `a()`, `b()` and `c()` representing the arguments in any order, and/or in parallel.

```
int res = f(a(), b(), c());
```

Comment: About `int x = someFunction(a, b);`: You mean, like `int rows = stmt.executeUpdate()` ? :-)

Comment: Yes. That's possibly the biggest side-effect a function could have!

Comment: @BrianAgnew Lukas's example really bothers me. This means that java creators neglected their own recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

Side-effect of an expression is mostly an assignment to variable during evaluation of the expression.

Notice the code:

```
int x = 5, y = 7;
while ((z = x-- + --y) > 0 ) {
    console.out("What is 'z' now? " + z);
    console.out("How many times will this be printed?");
}
```

Evaluation of the condition has 3 side-effects:

- decrementing `x`
- decrementing `y`
- assignment to `z`

Looks twisted, isn't it?